# No default constructor and errors out

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Error received:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘stout::SCGI::SCGI()’
```

Code:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <vector>

#include "../../../../stout/cgi/scgi/scgi.hpp"

class SCGITest : public ::testing::Test
{
protected:
    int string_length;
    std::vector<char> netstring;
    stout::SCGI scgi;

public:
    SCGITest()
    { 
        const char *c_netstring = 
            "70:CONTENT_LENGTH\00027\0"
            "SCGI\0001\0"
            "REQUEST_METHOD\0POST\0"
            "REQUEST_URI\0/deepthought\0"
            ","
            "What is the answer to life?";

        string_length = 102;

        for(int i = 0; i < string_length; ++i)
        {
            netstring.push_back(c_netstring[i]);
        }

        // SHOULD CALL stout::SCGI::SCGI(const std::vector<char>&)
        this->scgi = stout::SCGI scgi {netstring};
        scgi.init();
    }
};

TEST_F(SCGITest, NetstringSize)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(netstring.size(), string_length);
}

TEST_F(SCGITest, SCGILength)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(scgi.get_length(), 70);
}

TEST_F(SCGITest, SCGIContentLength)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(scgi.get_header("CONTENT_LENGTH"), "27");
}

TEST_F(SCGITest, SCGIVersion)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(scgi.get_header("SCGI"), "1");
}

TEST_F(SCGITest, SCGIRequestMethod)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(scgi.get_header("REQUEST_METHOD"), "POST");
}

TEST_F(SCGITest, SCGIRequestURI)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(scgi.get_header("REQUEST_URI"), "/deepthought");
}

TEST_F(SCGITest, SCGIRequestBody)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(scgi.get_request_body(), "What is the answer to life?");
}
```

Question:

When I try and construct and object of type `stout::SCGI::SCGI` using the constructor `stout::SCGI::SCGI(const std::vector<char>&)` it fails in the above code with the error message shown at the top of this post.

It seems that before the constructor has finished it has already tried to call the default (empty) constructor for the scgi private member variable. I do not want an empty constructor on my class and have had to temporarily add one to fix this issue while I investigate it.

I've read other questions regarding this issue but can't seem to find a solution for this particular case.

If it matters I'm compiling the above code using G++ 4.9.2 on Arch Linux with the `-std=c++14` flag.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Google Test. `scgi(netstring);` attempts to call the function `scgi` with the argument `netstring`. This clearly cannot work when `scgi` is neither a function nor anything that resembles a function.

Comment: @hwd Ah. Care to provide an answer with a solution so I can upvote you and mark the question as answered?

Comment: I didn't post it as an answer because I don't have one. For now, I can only tell you what the problem is, not how to solve that problem.

Comment: @hwd I've updated the question removing the erroneous google test stuff and fixed that particular issue you mentioned in the first comment. I've also updated it with the error message that is displayed when that has been fixed.

Comment: Why dont you use the mem initializer list ? `SCGITest() : scgi (netstring) { ... }`

Comment: @quantdev: Because he doesn't know about it yet.

Comment: @hvd: That is _not_ the stated problem. The compiler error has nothing to do with it at all.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yeah I noticed, +1

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Did you also notice that Cromulent updated the question in response to my comments? :) Look at the edit history, the initial revision of this question showed a different error message, and that different error message was caused by what I pointed out in my comment.

Comment: @hvd: Oh, I see! He entirely changed the question. GRrrrrr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `stout::SCGI` type has no default constructor, yet you are not *initialising* `this->scgi`. Sure, you're assigning to it at the end of your constructor body, but that's not at all the same thing.

You need to *initialise* any members that are `const` or which cannot be default-constructed:

```
struct Foo
{
   stout::SCGI scgi;

   Foo()
     : scgi(/* ctor arguments here */)   // this is a "member initialisation list"
   {};
};
```

---

Also, the following is simply not valid syntax:

```
this->scgi = stout::SCGI scgi {netstring};
```

That lone `scgi` is clearly superfluous. At *best*, you want:

```
this->scgi = stout::SCGI{netstring};
```

However, once you're initialising `this->scgi` instead of waiting to assign to it, then this goes away completely.

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem. I guess I should use initialiser lists more often. I was caught out by the fact that the constructor calls the default constructor unless you provide your own initialisation in the initialiser list.

Comment: @Cromulent: The member has to be constructed _somehow_! Unless you give it arguments, only the default constructor can be used.

Answer (score 1):

What is `scgi` supposed to be here? I think you just want

```
this->scgi = stout::SCGI {netstring};
```